# Oracle SQL regexp_substr to find the numbers in a string

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I want use regexp_substr to return the number after the characters from a string value

eg. 
     String Value         return
     100AUS50             50
     100AUS100            100
     100AUS500            500
     Jan-20               20
     Four200              200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below to get the number

```
 select regexp_substr(column,'\d+$') from TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this using exclusively standard string functions (no regular expressions). The `rtrim` function simply **removes** the digits at the end of the input string. Then `replace` replaces that string (the input string **minus** the digits at the end) from the original string - therefore leaving the "digits at the end" in the output.

```
with
  sample_data (str) as (
    select '100AUS50'  from dual union all
    select '100AUS100' from dual union all
    select '100AUS500' from dual union all
    select 'Jan-20'    from dual union all
    select 'Four200'   from dual union all
    select null        from dual union all
    select '200abc'    from dual union all
    select '3'         from dual
  )
select str, replace(str, rtrim(str, '0123456789')) as last_digits
from   sample_data
;

STR       LAST_DIGITS
--------- -----------
100AUS50  50       
100AUS100 100      
100AUS500 500      
Jan-20    20       
Four200   200      

200abc             
3         3
```

In the past I would just have said "standard string functions are generally faster than regular expressions". As luck would have it, though, I just answered the same question on OTN a few days ago, and the poster asked about the performance comparison. On a sample of 1.5 million input strings, the solution I just showed here was five times faster (0.86 seconds vs. 4.4 seconds for the regexp solution). https://community.oracle.com/message/15598613#15598613